# Stop the Auto start Tomcat on startup in Ubuntu

Tags: tomcat

When I run ubuntu, the tomcat server I have installed runs automatically and I have to switch it off manually. I want tomcat not to start automatically on boot. How to disable tomcat's startup on boot?

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, it looks like you have Tomcat installed as a service.

Based on this assumption and assuming you have the appropriate persmissions:

Find the service name of tomcat:

```
service --status-all
```

Then disable the service:

```
systemctl disable <service>
```